# Can we confirm $\sum_x{x!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, finite-differences

According to [Wikipedia's article on indefinite sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum), they list the following formula near the bottom of the page:

$$\displaystyle \sum_x{\Gamma(x)}=(-1)^{x+1}\Gamma(x)\frac{\Gamma(1-x,-1)}{e}+C$$

However, in Mathematica 7.0.1, I get the following:

$$\displaystyle\sum_x{(x-1)!} = $$
$$\displaystyle \sum_x{\Gamma(x)} = (-1)^{x+2}\Gamma(x+1)\frac{\Gamma(1-(x+1),-1)}{e}+ (-1)^{2}\Gamma(1)\frac{\Gamma(0,-1)}{e}$$

Where I've substituted $(-1)^{2}\Gamma(1)\frac{\Gamma(0,-1)}{e}$ for $C$.

Can someone please confirm that my equations are correct?  I'm using this formula for an important algorithm, and I'd like to be certain that the math checks out.  Thanks!

Comment: The wiki page is correct, its difference delta is $\Gamma(x)$. The other answer's difference delta is $\Gamma(x+1) = x!$.

Comment: @Sasha: Thanks for correcting my math.

Comment: Well in Mathematica I got 

$$\sum_{x=0}^{n}x!=-(-1)^n \Gamma (n+2) \text{Subfactorial}[-n-2]-\text{Subfactorial}[-1]-1$$